# How can I route traffic back through the interface it came through for Docker

Tags: iptables, docker, linux-networking, gre

Currently I have a setup with 1 physical NIC with a public IP address, a standard docker environment and a GRE tunnel & bridge. If I run a container on a port, lets say 80, I'll be able to connect directly to the container via the public IP address.

However when attempting to connect via the GRE tunnel the traffic is routed back to the default route.

An attempted connection via the tunnel:

```
00:52:43.899400 tun0 In  IP {client_ip}.57122 > {tunnel_ip}.80: Flags [S], seq 1853400133, win 64240, options [mss 1400,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
00:52:43.899501 enp3s0f0 Out IP {tunnel_ip}.80 > {client_ip}.57122: Flags [S.], seq 3563157661, ack 1853400134, win 64240, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,wscale 7], length 0
```

And a successful connection via the public IP:

```
00:52:48.822480 enp3s0f0 In  IP {client_ip}.57112 > {public_ip}.80: Flags [P.], seq 3944436694:3944437201, ack 1907727361, win 1029, length 507
00:52:48.823843 enp3s0f0 Out IP {public_ip}.80 > {client_ip}.57112: Flags [P.], seq 1:109, ack 507, win 501, length 108
```

So my issue is that traffic is being routed from `tunnel -> docker container -> public interface` rather than returning to the tunnel. I've read multiple articles around the docker networking subject but couldn't find anything specific about this sort of issue. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to mark incoming packets (entering the the virtual nic), and then, setup routing rules based on the mark, and eventually a secondary routing table. Sometimes, source-based routing can also work.

See here:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4420/reply-on-same-interface-as-incoming

Answer (score 0):

Working on a the same problem here, although with WireGuard and not GRE tunnel. The host provides both local services (SSH, Nginx reverse proxy) and docker container services (IMAP, SMTP, ...).

Other communication from host to internet still uses default route on public interface, ignoring the tunnel.

These (`PostUp` directives) should give a hint how it works:

- Any NEW *connection* from tunnel interface `wg0` *is marked* with number 2.
- Any returning *packets* from application networking level on host (OUTPUT chain) *are marked* with the same mark as the connection mark (2).
- Any returning *packets* from DNATed connections (docker containers) *are marked* with the same mark as the connection mark (2).

The packets must be marked *before* routing or re-routing decisions are made - see the netfilter diagram https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/37/Netfilter-packet-flow.svg/2560px-Netfilter-packet-flow.svg.png

```
# cat /etc/wireguard/wg0.conf 

[Interface]
Address = 10.0.37.2/24
PrivateKey = redacted

# If `AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0`, then wg-quick forces a default route to _every_ packet to go via
# WG tunnel. If we want to keep default route untouched, set:
Table = off

# And create routing manually only for WG related communication.
PostUp = iptables -t mangle -I PREROUTING 1 -i wg0 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j CONNMARK --set-mark 2
PostUp = iptables -t mangle -I OUTPUT 1 -m connmark --mark 2 -j CONNMARK --restore-mark
PostUp = iptables -t mangle -I PREROUTING 2 -m connmark --mark 2 -j CONNMARK --restore-mark
PostUp = ip rule add fwmark 2 lookup 2
PostUp = ip rule add table main suppress_prefixlength 0
PostUp = ip route add default dev wg0 table 2
PostUp = sysctl -q net.ipv4.conf.all.src_valid_mark=1
PostUp = sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.wg0.rp_filter=2

# Removal when `wg0` goes down
PostDown = iptables -t mangle -D PREROUTING -i wg0 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j CONNMARK --save-mark
PostDown = iptables -t mangle -D OUTPUT -m connmark --mark 2 -j CONNMARK --restore-mark
PostDown = iptables -t mangle -D PREROUTING 2 -m connmark --mark 2 -j CONNMARK --restore-mark
PostDown = ip rule del fwmark 2 table 2
PostDown = ip rule del table main suppress_prefixlength 0
PostDown = ip route del default dev wg0 lookup 2


[Peer]
Endpoint = my.vps.server:51800
PublicKey = redacted
PresharedKey = redacted
AllowedIPs = 10.0.37.1/32,0.0.0.0/0
PersistentKeepalive = 25
```

The above is a more laborious solution than the source based routing proposed by this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/23345

However, the source based routing does not seem adequate for a host, which can be accessed from the same public IP address via two interfaces (the local interface and the tunnel).